# matTextareaAutosize does not work in Angular Material 6.4.2

Tags: angular6, angular-material-6

I am trying apply auto-sizing on textarea in angular material 6.4.2 like below -

```
<mat-form-field>
      <textarea matInput [matTextareaAutosize]="true" placeholder="Task description" formControlName="description" [errorStateMatcher]="ErrorMatcher">
       </textarea>
</mat-form-field>
```

But it is throwing following error: Can't bind to 'matTextareaAutosize' since it isn't a known property of 'textarea'

What the wrong in my code?

Comment: in the docs, they stated that  you should use cdkTextareaAutosize directive

Answer (score 2):

in you `app.moudle`

```
import {  MatInputModule } from '@angular/material';
```

and then add `MatInputModule` to your `app.moudle` imports

Answer (score 1):

In Angular v14 this attribute has changed to `cdkTextareaAutosize`. The import changes to

```js
import {MatInputModule} from '@angular/material/input';
```